# Check if a folder exist in a directory and create them using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How can I check if directory `C:/` contains a folder named `MP_Upload`, and if it does not exist, create the folder automatically?

I am using Visual Studio 2005 C#.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

This should help:

```
using System.IO;
...

string path = @"C:\MP_Upload";
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Answer (score 188):

```
using System.IO;
...

Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\MP_Upload");
```

[Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) does exactly what you want: It creates the directory if it does not exist yet. **There's no need to do an explicit check first.**

> Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they already exist or unless some part of path is invalid. The path parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path. If the directory already exists, this method does nothing.

(This also means that all directories *along the path* are created if needed: `CreateDirectory(@"C:\a\b\c\d")` suffices, even if `C:\a` does not exist yet.)

---

Let me add a word of caution about your choice of directory, though: Creating a folder directly below the system partition root `C:\` is frowned upon. Consider letting the user choose a folder or creating a folder in `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` instead (use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) for that). The MSDN page of the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration contains a list of special operating system folders and their purposes.

Comment: This has come up on several other threads. Even though you don't need to check, it does make the intent of the code more clear, increasingly readability for an outsider. So keeping the check could be a good thing.

Comment: @MattJ.: In that case, I'd rather add a short comment than a useless function call. I agree that this behavior is not obvious, but, on the other hand, naming it (more aptly) `EnsureDirectoryExists` would have made the method harder to find.

Comment: Somewhat of a note: `Directory.CreateDirectory` will throw if the folder name matches an existing filename.

Answer (score 13):

```
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"c:\mp_upload"))
{
     System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\mp_upload");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work

```
if(!Directory.Exists(@"C:\MP_Upload")) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\MP_Upload");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String path = Server.MapPath("~/MP_Upload/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DirCombination 
{
    public partial class DirCombination : Form
    {
        private const string _Path = @"D:/folder1/foler2/folfer3/folder4/file.txt";
        private string _finalPath = null;
        private string _error = null;

        public DirCombination()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!FSParse(_Path))
                Console.WriteLine(_error);
            else
                Console.WriteLine(_finalPath);
        }

        private bool FSParse(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] Splited = path.Replace(@"//", @"/").Replace(@"\\", @"/").Replace(@"\", "/").Split(':');
                string NewPath = Splited[0] + ":";
                if (Directory.Exists(NewPath))
                {                    
                    string[] Paths = Splited[1].Substring(1).Split('/');

                    for (int i = 0; i < Paths.Length - 1; i++)
                    {
                        NewPath += "/";
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Paths[i]))
                        {
                            NewPath += Paths[i];
                            if (!Directory.Exists(NewPath))
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(NewPath);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Paths[Paths.Length - 1]))
                    {
                        NewPath += "/" + Paths[Paths.Length - 1];
                        if (!File.Exists(NewPath))
                            File.Create(NewPath);
                    }
                    _finalPath = NewPath;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    _error = "Drive is not exists!";
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _error = ex.Message;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```