# make sure folder exist before create file inside this folder

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Check if folder exist in directory and create them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092160/c-sharp-check-if-folder-exist-in-directory-and-create-them)

i have application who create files and need to put them in specific folder,  what is he best solution for check if the folder exist and if not create one ? (i am a new developer)

Comment: Duplicate of - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092160/c-sharp-check-if-folder-exist-in-directory-and-create-them][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092160/c-sharp-check-if-folder-exist-in-directory-and-create-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Directory.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx). Here is a sample code for you.

```
string path = @"C:\MyFolder";
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

This method is in `System.IO` namespace

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:\\temp"))
{
   //Folder exists
}
else
{
    //Folder does not exist
}
```

Comment: and if this folder didn't exist ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

It will check if the directory exists and if yes it simply does nothing. So the before hand check with `Directory.Exists()` is simply not needed.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092195/57488).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `Directory.Exists()` method. [MSDN doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)

```
string path = "c:\\MyDirectory";

if (!Directory.Exists( path )) {
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```