# Get path and create files dynamically

Tags: c#

I want to create a file in application data directory and save data from barcode list into that file. Can anybody help me with this code?

```
try
{
    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy.HH-mm-ss");
    File.Create("E:\\myfile.txt" + timestamp);

    // Add some text to file

    FileStream fstm = new FileStream("E:\\myfile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fstm);
    writer.Write(InputData);
    writer.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex) {

    MessageBox.Show("prblm : " + ex.Message,
                "Barcode List",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, your question is not a "good question" yet, so people are unlikely to be able to help you. What exact problem are you facing? Do you get an error message? What happens, what should happen and how do the two differ? You can use the "edit" link below your question to improve it.

Comment: prblm occured a part of the path is missing, i want to get the path of application data directory and want to create a folder there with timstamp in its name and further i want to save the above file(myfile.txt)in that folder

Comment: the error shown is a part of the path is missing, but now i want to use the logic mentioned in above comment

Answer (score 2):

You can gain access to the `appdata` directory via the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum.  There are two that you might be interested in, `CommonApplicationData` (non user specific data) and `LocalApplicationData` (user specific data).

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(BarCodeList.Text).ToList();
if (!lines.Any())
{
    return;
}
var dir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\" +
            DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
File.WriteAllLines(dir + @"\myFile.txt", lines);
```

Comment: i want add a folder in the application data and in that folder file will be saved.

Comment: @user3012548 I have updated my example to check if a folder with the current date exists and if not, create it.  You can obviously give your folder what ever name you like.

Comment: +1. Note that `if (!Directory.Exists)` [is not required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9092195/87698).

Comment: @Veleous: You're welcome! And while we're at it: With [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx) you don't need the StreamWriter nor the loop.

Comment: @Heinzi - See this is what I like about SO, you attempt to help someone and often learn new things yourself.  Thanks again.