# How to get parent directory in a path c#?

Tags: c#

it is my path example `E:\test\img\sig.jpg`
I want to get `E:\test\img` to create directory
i try split but it be img
so I try function Directory.CreateDirectory and the path is `E:\test\img\sig.jpg\`
say me a ideas?

Comment: Please could you _edit_ your question to show us what you've tried, then we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the parent directory in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875904/how-do-i-find-the-parent-directory-in-c)

Comment: Just google it before asking question

Comment: may be you should change your title. In your example the parent directory would be: `E:\test`

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way is to use [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname):

```
string file = @"E:\test\img\sig.jpg";
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file); // results in @"E:\test\img"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns the directory information for the specified path string.

```
string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Path` class contains a lot of useful methods for path handling, which are more reliable than manual string manipulation:

```
var directoryComponent = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"E:\test\img\sig.jpg");
// yields `E:\test\img`
```

For completeness, I'd like to mention `Path.Combine`, which does the opposite:

```
var dirAndFile = Path.Combine(@"E:\test\img", "sig.jpg");
// no more checking for trailing slashes, hooray!
```

To create the directory, you can use `Directory.Create`. Note that [it is not necessary to check if the directory exists first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092195/87698).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be :

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(@"E:\test\img\sig.jpg");
if (f.Exists)
{
    string dirName= f.DirectoryName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to find the directory name.
System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"E:\test\img\sig.jpg");
string dirname = fi.DirectoryName;

and to create the directory
Directory.CreateDirectory(dirname );