# Whats a nicer way of searching a list for a specific property

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a folder system, and there is a rule where you're not allowed to add multiple folders to the same directories. I have the below logic when adding the folder.

```
// CHECK TO SEE IF FOLDER NAME ALREADY EXISTS 
if (areaListViewIsVisible)
{
    foreach (Folder folder in areaList)
    {
        if (pResult.Text == folder.Title)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You cannot add a folder with the same name.", "OK");
            return;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    if (productListViewVisible)
    {
        foreach (Folder item in productList)
        {
            if (pResult.Text == item.Title)
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You cannot add a folder with the same name.", "OK");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
//
```

This seems like a bad way of checking, Can you recommend a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: create a path for the new folder and check if that path already exists. refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092187/2417602)

Comment: This question is more a code review request, rather than a to-the-point problem description. This doesn't belong here, maybe it does on Code Review.

Comment: Just refactor the foreach loop into a separate check function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have added `ToLower()` to avoid any case issues while comparing the `names`.

```
if ((areaListViewIsVisible && areaList.Any(folder => folder.Title.ToLower() == pResult.Text.ToLower())||
    (productListViewVisible && productListareaList.Any(folder => folder.Title.ToLower() == pResult.Text.ToLower()))
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You cannot add a folder with the same name.", "OK");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Which is more efficient, to have two if statements using Alex's solution or querying both in one if statement like you've done?

Comment: @SeanDavies that depends totally on your code structure, if you have to perform different task for product and area then you need to have two different `if` condition else if the both have the same task(as you've asked) then there is no need to have two `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use method Any of LINQ:

```
if(areaListViewIsVisible && areaList.Any(folder => folder.Title == pResult.Text))
{
     await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You cannot add a folder with the same name.", "OK");
     return;
}
```